# SharePoint list to lookup contact or account from CRM 2011

Tags: lookup-column, custom-list, contacts

I have a SharePoint site and I would like to be able to create a list of which one column will be linked to a customer account.

I have seen products that sync data between CRM 2011 and SharePoint (not really what I want as the CRM will be the single data source), and I have also seen some pretty heavy code in the form of plugins.

I thought this would be a common requirement but cannot find anything solid on google - I have read about BCS, self developed plugins with Visual Studio and paid for commercial plugins, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check these detailed links out to see if its what your looking for?

http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/integrating-dynamics-crm-data-into-sharepoint-2010/

http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/crm-2011-integration-with-sharepoint-taking-a-deeper-look/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/anand_nigam/archive/2011/12/04/crm-2011-and-sharepoint-2010-integration-part-1.aspx

intergrate crm and sharepoint visual studios
http://crmandsharepoint.codeplex.com/

sharepoint list component with crm
http://crmscape.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/ms-crm-2011-sharepoint-list-component.html

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 List Component for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010(download)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5283

I hope these all are what your looking for or guide you into the right direction to get you going!

Answer (score 0):

Also some code example how to use lookup field:

```
BusinessEntityCollection becEntityColl = null;                 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_testId))
{
    becEntityColl = CRM.QueryEntity(service, EntityName.account, new string[] { "new_ownid" }, new string[] { _testId });

    if (becEntityColl != null && becEntityColl.BusinessEntities != null && becEntityColl.BusinessEntities.Length > 0)
    {
        account acc = (account)becEntityColl.BusinessEntities[0];
        Lookup luField= new Lookup();
        luField.Value = new Guid(acc.accountid.Value.ToString());
        luField.name = acc.new_name;
        crmBusinessEntities.mpc_vakuuttaja = luField;
    }
}
```